# Inject JSRuntime into Blazor TestHost

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In an attempt to unit test my Blazor server-side components/pages I am using the `TestHost` provided on [the Github repo SteveSandersonMS/BlazorUnitTestingPrototype](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorUnitTestingPrototype), found reading [this article](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/08/29/blazor-unit-testing-prototype/).
My pages make use of the [blazor radzen components library](https://blazor.radzen.com/)

I have managed to inject the `DbContext` and all other components required by my own code, but the Radzen library requires an instance of the `IJSRuntime` interface and the `TestHost` must be provided an already instantiated object.

I checked the type instantiated by injecting an `IJSRuntime` in a view and it's a `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime`, which is an abstract class with a protected constructor. I've search throught the provided DLLs for an instantiable type that implemented `IJSRuntime` but couldn't find one.

**The question:**
How to instantiate an implementation of `IJSRuntime` for manual injection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mock :

- Add a package reference to [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq) (you can use the mock lib of your choice, I prefer Moq)
- Add a using statement to Moq namespace

```cs
using Moq;
```

- Create the mock for IJSRuntime

```cs
var jsRuntimeMock = new Mock<IJSRuntime>();
```

- Inject the mock in the `TestHost` DI

```cs
var host = new TestHost();
host.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddSingleton(p => jsRuntimeMock.Object);
}
```

Comment: That ... is so ... OBVIOUS !
That's why I shouldn't work at 1am ...

Comment: ah wait, i'm not sure if that actually workds. I'll have to test it. I don't know if test host is really capable of testing a component that has JSInterop requirements. I'll test this with mocking and let you know

Comment: Trust me it works, I use it in this project : https://github.com/Aguafrommars/TheIdServer/blob/9eb1d3d48e7bd246a65e6e066779156c2de29817/test/Aguacongas.TheIdServer.IntegrationTest/TestUtils.cs#L134

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll look into it !

Comment: Guys, where does TestHost class come from? D:

Comment: @DanielVega from [the Github repo SteveSandersonMS/BlazorUnitTestingPrototype](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorUnitTestingPrototype)